# My return result from Promise is <pending>

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using `Sequelize` database `orm` and by this code as

```
model.create(
    {
        username: 'John'
    } ).then( function (result) {
    return result.userUniqueId;
} );
```

I can create new user in database and i can print `userUniqueId` inside of `then()`.

after create user I want to use returned `userUniqueId` in other functions or only print that on console, but i can't return `result.userUniqueId` from that, for resolve this problem I'm trying to use `Promise` to get result then I deployed that to:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    createNewUser: function (model) {
        return new Promise(
            function (resolve, reject) {
                model.create(
                    {
                        username: 'John'
                    } ).then( function (result) {
                    return result.userUniqueId;
                } );
            } )
            .then( function (result) {
                resolve( result.userUniqueId );
            } );
    },
};
```

but i get this result outside of `createNewUser` function as `console.log( controller.createNewUser( models.users ) );`

Result:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

How can i resolve this problem?

## UPDATE:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    createNewUser: function (model) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            return model.create(
                {
                    username: 'John'
                })
                .then(function (result) {
                    return result.userUniqueId;
                })
                .then(value => resolve(value));
        });
    },
};
```

and

```
var userId = controller.createNewUser(models.users)
        .then(function (userId) {
            return userId;
        });

console.log(userId);
```

print Promise object

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem. Aside from promises that are created resolved or rejected (directly with `Promise.resolve()` and `Promise.reject()` respectively), all Promises are created in "pending" state.

That state will change when the Promise's `resolve()` function is called.

As an aside, you fell into the Promise constructor antipattern. Instead of this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  doSomething()
    .then(value => resolve(value));
});
```

Just do

```
return doSomething()
```

No need to wrap Promises with additional Promise constructors.

Comment: my post updated with your help, but i get Promise object again

Answer (score 0):

Just as with any promise, you need to use `then` to access its result value:

```
controller.createNewUser( models.users )
    .then(function (userId) {
         // do something with the ID
    });
```

You can't access the value from the promise directly because the promise may not be resolved yet.

Also as Madara points out, you have fallen into the explicit promise construction antipattern. Get rid of the extraneous code:

```
module.exports = {
    createNewUser: function (model) {
         return model.create(
             {
                 username: 'John'
             } )
             .then( function (result) {
                 return result.userUniqueId;
             } );
    },
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry sir, i think i dont understand exactly whats your mean, after change my code to your code as `module.exports` i get Promise object and your code as `controller.createNewUser( models.users ) ...` dont resolve my problem because i must be use result inside `then()` and i want to assign variable as `createNewUser` function

Comment: My post updated sir

Comment: @tux-world Show us the code where you're trying to use the return value of `createNewUser`, and not just a single line.

Comment: My post updated sir, Thanks

Comment: @tux-world There is no way to make your code work the way you have written it there. The whole reason promises are involved is that the value is not available right away. Your question here is an extremely common one, please see this for an explanation of the situation and how to approach it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call